# Get the position and size of a dialog component in react native

Tags: react-native

I am using a Dialog component from 'react-native-paper' in a simple functional component like:

```
...
const myScreen = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
       Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', frames => {
           // get the Dialog component measures
       });
   );
   return (
      <View>
         ...
         <Portal>
            <Dialog>
            ...
            </Dialog>
         </Portal>
     </View>
   );
 }
```

I need to get the size and position of the dialog on screen in the useEffect.
I have tried every suggested solution and nothing seems to work.